# I have a xml file with code in it and i need to integrate that code in as3. How can i do that?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, action

I want to add several lines of code to flash AS3. How would i be able to do that if those lines are in a xml and the data that is needed is taken with a function that loads the xml.
I need to add those lines in flash? How can i do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<game>


<!-- "Level id" number is not required. Just I added it for fast calculating -->



<!-- Page 1 -->

<Level id="1" star3="6" star2="10">
<Row>2,2,2,2</Row>
<Row>2,2,0,0</Row>
<Row>2,2,2,2</Row>
<Row>1,1,4,4</Row>
<Row>1,1,4,4</Row>
</Level>


<Level id="2" star3="8" star2="12">
<Row>2,2,2,2</Row>
<Row>2,2,2,2</Row>
<Row>0,1,1,0</Row>
<Row>3,3,4,4</Row>
<Row>3,3,4,4</Row>
</Level>


<Level id="3" star3="8" star2="12">
<Row>1,0,1,1</Row>
<Row>1,0,1,1</Row>
<Row>1,1,4,4</Row>
<Row>1,1,4,4</Row>
<Row>1,1,1,1</Row>
</Level>


<Level id="4" star3="8" star2="12">
<Row>3,1,1,0</Row>
<Row>3,1,1,0</Row>
<Row>2,2,2,2</Row>
<Row>3,3,4,4</Row>
<Row>3,3,4,4</Row>
</Level>
.
.
.
etc
```

The function to load this xml is the following one:

```
//playBtn.visible=false;
loadXML();
//loading data from the xml file.
function loadXML():void {
var loader:URLLoader=new URLLoader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,completeXMLHandler);
//defining request.;
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("data.xml");
//try catch any error
try {
    loader.load(request);
} catch (error:Error) {
    trace('error');
}
}

//loading function
function completeXMLHandler(event:Event):void {

var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
var result:XML = new XML(loader.data);
//defining new xml document
var myXML:XMLDocument=new XMLDocument();
myXML.ignoreWhite = true;
myXML.parseXML(result.toXMLString());
//defining node;
var node:XMLNode = myXML.firstChild;
//defining levelNum from the lenght of the node
totalLevel = int(node.childNodes.length);
//pushing the words and their clues to the array
//creating a temporary array for each level, than pushing temporary array to the main array (dataArray)
for (var i:int=0; i<totalLevel; i++) {
    scoreArray.push(9999)
    var temp_array:Array=new Array();
    var row:int = int(node.childNodes[i].childNodes.length);
        starInfoArray.push(node.childNodes[i].attributes.star3+"_"+node.childNodes[i].attributes.star2);
    for (var j:int=0; j<row; j++) {
        var myData = node.childNodes[i].childNodes[j].firstChild.nodeValue;
        temp_array.push(myData);
    }
    dataArray.push(temp_array);
}
}
```

Please tell me if you need more details.

Comment: your actionscript code looks lke a mix of actionscript 2 and 3. What is XMLDocument and why do you need it ? (you can parse straight away with the XML class)

Comment: thx for your reply. i bought this game. it's only as3 don't know where you see as2...
there is that data.xml where you can find that code and there are the levels. So i need to integrate them in that function so the data.xml isn't needed anymore because when i publish the app for mobile release the game doesn't work without the data from the xml. please offer a solution to this.

Comment: you can embed the XML at compile time: if you're using Flash Builder using the Embed tag or if you're using Flash Professional, simply use the xml as a variable (E.g. `var gameXML:XML = <game><level/></game>`)

Comment: ok but when i publish the apk the xml isn't compiled... so no informatian from the xml is kept. I'm using flash cs6. Isn't there a way to add the xml like i'm adding the ANE files?

Comment: I'm not sure you understood what I meant: in your actionscript code create a new variable of type XML and have it's value be that whole XML you're trying to load. You won't need to load any XML, it will already be in your code and it should compile along with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can embed the xml into your existing actionscript 3 code and access it straight away.

Here's what I mean:

```
var gameXML:XML = <game>
    <Level id="1" star3="6" star2="10">
        <Row>2,2,2,2</Row>
        <Row>2,2,0,0</Row>
        <Row>2,2,2,2</Row>
        <Row>1,1,4,4</Row>
        <Row>1,1,4,4</Row>
    </Level>
    <Level id="2" star3="8" star2="12">
        <Row>2,2,2,2</Row>
        <Row>2,2,2,2</Row>
        <Row>0,1,1,0</Row>
        <Row>3,3,4,4</Row>
        <Row>3,3,4,4</Row>
    </Level>
    <Level id="3" star3="8" star2="12">
        <Row>1,0,1,1</Row>
        <Row>1,0,1,1</Row>
        <Row>1,1,4,4</Row>
        <Row>1,1,4,4</Row>
        <Row>1,1,1,1</Row>
    </Level>
    <Level id="4" star3="8" star2="12">
        <Row>3,1,1,0</Row>
        <Row>3,1,1,0</Row>
        <Row>2,2,2,2</Row>
        <Row>3,3,4,4</Row>
        <Row>3,3,4,4</Row>
    </Level>
</game>;

//traverse the game config xml
for each(var level:XML in gameXML.Level.*){//go through each Leve node in the XML
    scoreArray.push(9999);
    starInfoArray.push(level.@star3+"_"+level.@star2);//access the start3 and start2 attributes
    var temp_array:Array = [];
    for each(var row:XML in level.Row.*) //go through each Row node in a Level and get the data 
        temp_array.push(row.text().toXMLString());//you might want to parse these strings at some point and get the int values
    dataArray.push(temp_array);
}
```

Note that the XML tags might need formatting if you get syntax errors (can't test the code at the moment)

Comment: although someone recommended to just add the file on the publish menu because there aren't very large performance changes. so both are good. thx a lot for your answer and time have a great day